# Painless script to add new fields into _source object when querying into elasticsearch v6.0.1

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index with the field mapping with one property (id: integer).
When I am querying into that index, I am able to get the correct response. Now, I want to add one extra fields into _source object at the query time using painless scripting. 
The elasticsearch version is 6.0.1.

I have already tried adding script as a field in the query block. But it throws an error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "root_cause": [
      {
        "type": "parsing_exception",
        "reason": "[term] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
        "line": 7,
        "col": 7
      }
    ],
    "type": "parsing_exception",
    "reason": "[term] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
    "line": 7,
    "col": 7
  },
  "status": 400
}
```

```
GET 20190719_candidate/candidate/_search
{
    "min_score": 0.001,
    "query": {
      "term": {
        "id": 1234
      }, 
      "script": {
        "script": {
          "inline": "doc['field_1'] = 'field_1_value'"
        }
      }
    }, 
    "from": 0,
    "size": 20
}
```

The expected result for _source object is:

```
{
  "id": "1234567",
  "field_1": "field_1_value"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the structure:

```
GET 20190719_candidate/candidate/_search
{
    "min_score": 0.001,
    "query": {
      "term": {
        "id": 1234
      }, 
      "script_fields": {
           "test1":{
                 "script": {
                      "lang": "painless",                       
                      "source": "'field_1_value'"
                 }
            }
      }
    }, 
    "from": 0,
    "size": 20
}
```

Take a look in this example:

```
GET /_search
{
    "query" : {
        "match_all": {}
    },
    "script_fields" : {
        "test1" : {
            "script" : {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": "doc['price'].value * 2"
            }
        },
        "test2" : {
            "script" : {
                "lang": "painless",
                "source": "doc['price'].value * params.factor",
                "params" : {
                    "factor"  : 2.0
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

source: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-body.html#request-body-search-script-fields

Answer (score 0):

> "root_cause": [
>         {
>           "type": "parsing_exception",
>           "reason": "[term] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]",
>           "line": 7,
>           "col": 7
>         }
>       ],

the error says that you have a malformed query, you have missed a closing bracket in line 7 to close the "query" attribute.

you query should be like:

```
GET 20190719_candidate/candidate/_search
{
    "min_score": 0.001,
    "query": {
      "term": {
        "id": 1234
      }}, 
      "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "inline": "doc['field_1'] = 'field_1_value'"
      }, 
    "from": 0,
    "size": 20
}
```